# Xen based AMI does not boot (/dev/xvda)

Tags: amazon-web-services, xen

Trying to create an AMI Instance Store within a xen based guest (VM: CentOS 6.6, 32 bit, PV).

'ec2-bundle-vol' only accepts /dev/xvda1 as a valid block device. If device entries are modified in /etc/fstab and /boot/grub/grub.conf before (/dev/sda1 or /dev/xvde1) the tool escapes with error-message 'Not a block device: (FatalError'.

Also tried 'bundle' options as:
--block-device-mapping ami=sda,root=/dev/sda1,swap=sda2

or using dedicated config files as:
--fstab /tmp/fstab \
--grub-config /tmp/grub.conf

without success. Found also an 'unknown' kernel-boot-option 'xen_blkfront.sda_is_xvda=1' but this fails completely at AWS boot.

If going on uploading (ec2-bundle-upload') with /dev/xvda finally the registered AMI Image does not boot.

AWS System Log:

> > blkfront: xvde1: barriers disabled
> >     Changing capacity of (202, 65) to 13312000 sectors
> >     xvde1: detected capacity change from 0 to 6815744000
> >     blkfront: xvde2: barriers disabled
> >     blkfront: xvde3: barriers disabled
> >     Changing capacity of (202, 66) to 312705024 sectors
> >     xvde2: detected capacity change from 0 to 160104972288
> >     Changing capacity of (202, 67) to 1835008 sectors
> >     xvde3: detected capacity change from 0 to 939524096
> >     dracut Warning: No root device "block:/dev/xvda1" found

/etc/fstab:
/dev/xvda1 / ext4 defaults 1 1
...

/boot/grub/grub.conf:
title CentOS Linux 6.6 (Custom AMI, hd0)
 root (hd0)
 kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.i686 ro root=/dev/xvda1 rd_NO_PLYMOUTH LANG=en_US.UTF-8 KEYTABLE=de selinux=0 rdshell console=ttyS0
 initrd /boot/initramfs-2.6.32-504.30.3.el6.i686.img

AWS-KERNEL:
eu-west-1, EU (Ireland) region AMI Image ID 32bit (hd0):
aki-68a3451f

cloud-init: 0.7.5-10.el6.centos.2.i686
using latest ec2-tools:
wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads/ec2-ami-tools.zip
wget http://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads/ec2-api-tools.zip

I'm pretty sure that this way (changing devices to 'xvde1', and as it's described in many tutorials) worked in the past. Has there anything changed in ec2-api tools or I'm missing something else? This problem drives me crazy and wastes my time for four days. Amazon support forum (ec2) has a lot of similar boot problems, but not this case. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!!!

> Blockquote